# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. S3 Bucket Http Post

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to an s3 bucket using HTTP post method following the tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html. But I am getting the following error every time

```
 Error
 <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
 <Message>
 The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you 
 provided. Check your key and signing method.
  </Message>
```

To make the request I've got the following form:

```
 <form action="http://mynewdulibucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Key to upload:
<input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://mynewdulibucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
Content-Type:
<input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
<input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20151229T000000Z" />

Tags for File:
<input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /> <br />
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
File:
<input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
<!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
```

The policy is the following:

```
{ "expiration": "2018-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
 "conditions": [
{"bucket": "mynewdulibucket"},
["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/MyPhoto.jpg"],
{"acl": "public-read"},
{"success_action_redirect": "http://mynewdulibucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
{"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
{"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
{"x-amz-credential": "XXXXXXXXX/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
{"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
{"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
]
  }
```

And the code to generate the policy and signature which I then paste into the relevant form fields is:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String policy_document = "{\"expiration\":\"2018-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\",\"conditions\":[{\"bucket\":\"mynewdulibucket\"},[\"starts-with\",\"$key\",\"user/user1/MyPhoto.jpg\"],{\"acl\":\"public-read\"},{\"success_action_redirect\":\"http://mynewdulibucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"},[\"starts-with\",\"$Content-Type\",\"image/\"],{\"x-amz-meta-uuid\":\"14365123651274\"},{\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\":\"AES256\"},[\"starts-with\",\"$x-amz-meta-tag\",\"\"],{\"x-amz-credential\":\"AKIAJQHQNWQ7FCTGNKQQ/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"},{\"x-amz-algorithm\":\"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"},{\"x-amz-date\":\"20151229T000000Z\"}]}";
    String encodedPolicy = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(policy_document.getBytes("UTF-8"))).replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
    String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    String signature = getSigning(secretKey, "20151229T000000Z", "us-east-1", "s3",encodedPolicy);

    //the following values get pasted into the form fields Policy and X-Amz-Signature respectively (see above XXXXX)
    System.out.println("base64 " + encodedPolicy);

    System.out.println("signature " + signature);

}


static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception
{
    String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
}

static String getSigning(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName,String base64signature) throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    //
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

    byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(base64signature, kSigning);

    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(signature));
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI your x-amz-date value is probably not what you want, as according to the link you provided "The upload must occur before noon UTC on December 30, 2015"

Comment: yes, that's why I've changed the expiration date to "expiration": "2018-12-30T12:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Please correct the policy to specify `["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"]`, try again, and update the question with the corrected content.  Also, don't suppress the policy from the form.  It isn't sensitive.

Comment: did you ever solve this george?

Answer (score -1):

This misleading error shows up when you haven’t authenticated properly.

Validate that either:

- your ~/.aws/config is correct.
- you’re providing API keys properly at invocation time.
- your environment variables are passing your credentials properly.
- the instance you’re running this from has the proper permissions assigned to its IAM role.

Comment: There's really nothing that I see in the question to justify any of these.  It is not obvious that `~/.aws/config` would even be read, there's no reference to environment variables, the "API keys" are hard-coded static strings, and no IAM roles are being used.

Comment: The only time I’ve ever seen AWS spitting out signature errors on S3 calls, it’s come down to the requestor not having authenticated properly. Am I missing something? Love to learn more if so!

Comment: A mismatched key and secret, or a typo in the secret, will cause the signature not to match, yes.  The issue here is that the specific suggestions you made don't match the material presented in the question.  Roles aren't being used, and OP is signing the request directly, not using an SDK.  Assuming `String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";` and the `AKIA...` in the credential are correct, the problem has to be in OPs signing algorithm or the signed policy not precisely matching the request the policy is intended to authenticate.